# Syncing Linux server data with data on my Mac

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, data-synchronization, backup

I have a Linux server that stores some files, and I want to sync them with my Mac.
I can mount the directory of the server, so after mounting it's just  directory to directory sync. There are thousands of files, so the sync tool should be smart enough to sync only the changed files.

Is there any Mac software out there that does this automatically (or at a scheduled time)? The expected action is as follows:

1. Mount the directory in a server.
2. Sync intelligently.
3. Unmount.

Comment: What you're after is `rsync`. This is a powerful cross-platform piece of software. It's on OS X & Linux distros out-of-the-box. There's some concern that the version of `rsync` that ships with OS X is outdated and doesn't handle resource forks and other things properly. `rsync` is 'smart' because it will only back-up the changed data. The rest of what you want can be achieved by a script but as to how to write such a script, I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the GUI-based [arRsync tool](http://arrsync.sourceforge.net/) for OS X with the use of `/net` to automount the share to achieve what you desire.

[The remote share will be automatically mounted as long as you access as `/net/hostname/exportname`](http://m.techrepublic.com/blog/mac/mounting-nfs-volumes-in-os-x/430). So use that path in arRsync and when you fire the sync it'll automount and then scan and sync just the deltas.

There's good old command line `rsync` available if you prefer. It ships with OS X. [Here is the manual page for it](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/rsync.1.html).

Comment: +1 for rsync.   Used in combination with a cron job (or osx's equivalent) you'll have a bullet proof sync machine.

Comment: You don't need to mount the target just use rsync protocol e.g. rsync options path target_machine::target_path

Comment: @Mark that `::` syntax tells `rsync` that the target machine is running an `rsync server`. That's generally not common, and not necessary if you use the `/net` auto-mount approach.

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox might also be of use. It provides automatic syncing of folders and does that in the "smart" way that you described.

It has clients of windows, linux and osx.

https://www.dropbox.com/